# cp: Error writing. File too large. Cannot copy anything more than 4.3 GB

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I know there are already many such questions asked, but none of them solved my issue. People keep mentioning that it's because of FAT32 which has maximum limit of 4 GB which is stupid. Why would the USB manufactures hand out new drives in FAT32 if the size limit is 32 GB or more? I have had used USB drives of upto 64 GB upto maximum limit in Windows back in the days when I used to copy big game files, never faced any this issue until now. Only facing this issue on Ubuntu.

People propose 2 solutions 1st is to change the drive's file format to something else, but don't explain how to do that? Second, what they explain is to split the file into multiple part which is stupid, why do I have to do that if my USB supports upto 32 GB capacity. The file that I'm trying to copy is merely 16 GB. I have to copy many files on multiple occasions, I don't have time and sanity to keep splitting and merging them one by one. I want to simply copy them to my USB drive without any issues.

Comment: *I have had used USB drives of upto 64 GB upto maximum limit in Windows* It has nothing to do with the OS, it has EVERYTHING to do with the file system - exFAT - many 64GB+ flash drives come formatted with that hasn't the limitations the old FAT32 has. FAT32 is still used in many for better compatibility. -1 for the (ignorant) rant in disguise and for not caring to educate yourself properly, all of this being public knowledge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Maximal_sizes  ... Compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an issue with the USB drive, it is an issue with the disk format. Yes, it is stupid that fat32 has a maximum of 4GB (2^32), but, drive manufacturers would prefer to format to fat32 as the majority of embedded devices only support fat32.

When selecting a better partition type, a good choice would be either EXT4 (if you are only using it on Linux boxes), or NTFS (If you need windows compatibility).

gparted is a graphical tool you can use to reformat your USB drive, and is what I would use.

You can also use parted, here is a quick example:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdb   # Select /dev/sdb to operate on
rm 1                   # Remove 1sst partition
mkpart ext4            # Create a new ext4 partition
quit                   # Write out new information
```

You don't need to know anything about the disklabel, but as an FYI, the 1st block of the disk is the disk label, and is typically either MBR or GPT. MBR is the old-school dos label, GPT is a modern replacement. The disk label identifies what the disk is, and underneath your disk label you can specify partitions. Partitions in turn are what get formatted to a specific type of file system.

If you wanted to be really fancy, you could also change the disk label to GPT while you are messing around with the partitions.

Comment: Can I directly run the parted commands like you showed instead of installing gparted? I hope that doesn't break anything up. Also, which disk format should I opt for? You showed ext4. I want to transfer a file from one Dell Ubuntu laptop to another. Which disk format would be ideal?

Comment: @VinRaghav Gparted is probably the easiest path forward if you are unsure of what is happening because it will graphically show you the device you are working on and what the changes will be. Yes you can use parted, but you wouldn't want to copy verbatim because your device names are likely different. EXT4 would be a good for your use case.

Comment: Your answer is a masterclass in patient, constructive reply to a slightly ranty question!